# Survey Force integration with cases

Tags: workflow, case, survey

I have a WFR designed to send a survey (using Survey Force app) when a case is closed. I choose to work with Survey Force because of the connection with the case object. Currently - the survey object hold the case id, but the case holds no data about the survey.
I want to produce a report with the following info - case ID, survey responses (2 questions in total), case owner. To do that I need to update the case with the survey responses. I have 2 fields on the case object (representing the 2 questions in my survey). How can I update these fields when the survey is taken?